# How can one set property values when initializing an object in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Given the following class:

```
class Test
  attr_accessor :name
end
```

When I create the object, I want to do the following:

```
t = Test.new {name = 'Some Test Object'}
```

At the moment, it results in the `name` attribute still being `nil`.

Is that possible without adding an initializer?

Comment: Ruling out an initialize method (is that what you meant?) makes things difficult. When creating new `Test` objects, should `name` get the same initialization each time? Or should it get a value specified in open code?

Comment: Motivation would be to do something similar to C# - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx

Comment: Is there something you doesn't like with the solution which I'm proposing ?

Comment: No, I do like it but you need to add an initialize step to the actual class. If you look at how C# does it, then it's a language feature and works against any C# class. 

What happens if I already have an initialize step? What if it's from a external lib?

Comment: @Ben did you ever find a solution to this? I am also after something like the C# object initializer

Answer (score 18):

ok,

I came up with a solution. It uses the initialize method but on the other hand do exactly what you want.

```
class Test
  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize(init)
    init.each_pair do |key, val|
      instance_variable_set('@' + key.to_s, val)
    end
  end

  def display
    puts @name
  end

end

t = Test.new :name => 'hello'
t.display
```

happy ? :)

---

Alternative solution using inheritance. Note, with this solution, you don't need to explicitly declare the attr_accessor!

```
class CSharpStyle
  def initialize(init)
    init.each_pair do |key, val|
      instance_variable_set('@' + key.to_s, val)
      instance_eval "class << self; attr_accessor :#{key.to_s}; end"
    end
  end
end

class Test < CSharpStyle
  def initialize(arg1, arg2, *init)
    super(init.last)
  end
end

t = Test.new 'a val 1', 'a val 2', {:left => 'gauche', :right => 'droite'}
puts "#{t.left} <=> #{t.right}"
```

Answer (score 9):

As mentioned by others, the easiest way to do this would be to define an `initialize` method. If you don't want to do that, you could make your class inherit from [Struct](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Struct.html).

```
class Test < Struct.new(:name)
end
```

So now:

```
>> t = Test.new("Some Test Object")
=> #<struct Test name="Some Test Object">
>> t.name
=> "Some Test Object"
```

Answer (score 8):

There is a general way of doing complex object initialization by
passing a block with necessary actions. This block is evaluated in the
context of the object to be initialized, so you have an easy access to
all instance variables and methods.

Continuing your example, we can define this generic initializer:

```
class Test
  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize(&block)
    instance_eval(&block)
  end 
end
```

and then pass it the appropriate code block:

```
t = Test.new { @name = 'name' }
```

or

```
t = Test.new do
  self.name = 'name'
  # Any other initialization code, if needed.
end
```

Note that this approach does not require adding much complexity
to the `initialize` method, per se.

Answer (score 1):

As previously mentioned, the sensible way to do this is either with a `Struct` or by defining an `Test#initialize` method. This is exactly what structs and constructors are for. Using an options hash corresponding to attributes is the closest equivalent of your C# example, and it's a normal-looking Ruby convention:

```
t = Test.new({:name => "something"})
t = Test.new(name: "something") # json-style or kwargs
```

But in your example you are doing something that looks more like variable assignment using `=` so let's try using a block instead of a hash. (You're also using `Name` which would be a constant in Ruby, we'll change that.)

```
t = Test.new { @name = "something" }
```

Cool, now let's make that actually work:

```
class BlockInit
  def self.new(&block)
    super.tap { |obj| obj.instance_eval &block }
  end
end

class Test < BlockInit
  attr_accessor :name
end

t = Test.new { @name = "something" }
# => #<Test:0x007f90d38bacc0 @name="something">
t.name
# => "something"
```

We've created a class with a constructor that accepts a block argument, which is executed within the newly-instantiated object.

Because you said you wanted to avoid using `initialize`, I'm instead overriding `new` and calling `super` to get the default behavior from `Object#new`. **Normally we would define `initialize` instead**, this approach isn't recommended except in meeting the specific request in your question.

When we pass a block into a subclass of `BlockInit` we can do more than just set variable... we're essentially just injecting code into the `initialize` method (which we're avoiding writing). If you also wanted an `initialize` method that does other stuff (as you mentioned in comments) you could add it to `Test` and not even have to call `super` (since our changes aren't in `BlockInit#initialize`, rather `BlockInit.new`)

Hope that's a creative solution to a very specific and intriguing request.

Answer (score 0):

The code you're indicating is passing parameters into the `initialize` function. You will most definitely have to either use `initialize`, or use a more boring syntax:

```
test = Test.new
test.name = 'Some test object'
```

Answer (score 0):

Would need to subclass Test (here shown with own method and initializer) e.g.:

```
class Test
  attr_accessor :name, :some_var

  def initialize some_var
    @some_var = some_var
  end

  def some_function
    "#{some_var} calculation by #{name}"
  end
end

class SubClassedTest < Test
  def initialize some_var, attrbs
    attrbs.each_pair do |k,v|
      instance_variable_set('@' + k.to_s, v)
    end
    super(some_var)
  end
end

tester = SubClassedTest.new "some", name: "james"
puts tester.some_function
```

outputs: `some calculation by james`

Answer (score 0):

You could do this.

```
class Test
   def not_called_initialize(but_act_like_one)
        but_act_like_one.each_pair do |variable,value|
            instance_variable_set('@' + variable.to_s, value)
            class << self
                    self
            end.class_eval do
                    attr_accessor variable
            end
        end
   end
end

(t = Test.new).not_called_initialize :name => "Ashish", :age => 33
puts t.name #=> Ashish
puts t.age  #=> 33
```

One advantage is that you don't even have to define your instance variables upfront using `attr_accessor`. You could pass all the instance variables you need through `not_called_initialize` method and let it create them besides defining the getters and setters.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to override `initialize` then you'll have to move up the chain and override `new`. Here's an example:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :bar, :baz

  def self.new(*args, &block)
    allocate.tap do |instance|
      if args.last.is_a?(Hash)
        args.last.each_pair do |k,v|
          instance.send "#{k}=", v
        end
      else
        instance.send :initialize, *args
      end
    end
  end

  def initialize(*args)
    puts "initialize called with #{args}"
  end
end
```

If the last thing you pass in is a Hash it will bypass `initialize` and call the setters immediately. If you pass anything else in it will call initialize with those arguments.