# How to build remote Webdriver for Chrome

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to run my Selenium tests against Chrome. When I initialize driver locally:

```
@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for( :chrome )
```

Everything works fine (I already put Chrome binary on my PATH)
But when I try to launch it remotely:

```
@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:remote, :url => 'http://' + SELENIUM_HOST + port + webdriver_hub, :desired_capabilities => :chrome)
```

I get the following error

> Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnhandledError: The path to the
>   chromedriver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver
>   system property; for more information, see
>   http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest
>   version can be downloaded from
>   http://code.google.com/p/chromium/downloads/list
>   (java.lang.IllegalStateException)

I am a bit confused there - how exactly should I set this system property? I found this code written in Java:

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
caps.setCapability("chrome.binary", "/path/to/where/chrome/is/installed/chrome.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/path/to/where/you/ve/put/chromedriver.exe");
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(caps);
```

but my tests are written in Ruby. RubyBindings don't talk about this issue  http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RubyBindings

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Actually the error message is slightly wrong. You don't *have* to set the system property, but the chromedriver executable needs to be available in the PATH on the remote machine (where the server is running).

If you want to specify the path as a property, you can do that when you launch the server, e.g.:

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/path/to/driver -jar selenium-server-standalone.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set path to your **cromedriver.exe** inside the code of the test. Its something like

```
System.setproperty();
```

in Java

I am also using Java based tests, so I cannot give you exact example for Ruby. But basically you have to tell your Ruby program where is the path to **chromedriver.exe**

Comment: Thanks for the tips, Pavel. But it is exactly what I am looking for - how to set up this property in Ruby.

Comment: I am not Ruby expert, so I dont have clue... But after some searching I found this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348621/ruby-setting-property-values-when-initializing-object Is that helpful? If not, maybe consider asking Ruby specific question

Answer (score 1):

Okay, guys. With the help I could find the answer. Check it out.

That is how you set up the driver on your local machine:

```
    @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:remote, :chrome :url => 'http://' + SELENIUM_HOST + port + webdriver_hub, :desired_capabilities => browser)
```

where

```
browser = ':chrome'
port = ':4444'
webdriver_hub = '/wd/hub'
```

On the remote machine running the server would be something like this

```
    java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.2.0.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="path/to/where/you/put/chromedriver.exe"
```

After run your tests from the local machine.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

I found the selected answer to be very misleading. It took me about an hour to release the mistake in it. The **node** is the one that should have the `webdriver.chrome.driver` property set, not the **hub**.

Therefore the selected answer's command should instead be:

`java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/path/to/driver -jar selenium-server-standalone.jar -role node`