# Creating generic constructor in ruby

Tags: ruby

I found this interesting answer :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2348854/169277

This is ok when you're trying to set instance variables it works really great.

Is there a way to apply the same logic or better one to create generic constructor like :

```ruby
def initialize(obj)
  obj.each do |k,v|
   #find the setter for each k and set the value v to and return newly created object
  end
end
```

If I had object `TestObject`:

```
class TestObject
attr_accessor :name, :surname, :sex
end
```

I was thinking to create it something like this:

```
TestObject.new({:name => 'Joe', :surname => 'Satriani'})
```

How would one achieve this?

So doing this would be a shorthand of :

```
t = TestObject.new
t.name = 'Joe'
t.surname = 'Satriani'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can use [send](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-send) to send arbitrary messages to an object. Since we're operating on `self` here, we can just invoke `send` directly.

```
def initialize(obj)
  obj.each do |k,v|
    send(:"#{k}=", v)
  end
end
```

For example, `TestObject.new({:name => 'Joe'})` will call `send "name=", "Joe"`.

Comment: You were missing do after each (I edited), otherwise answer what I was looking for. thanks

Comment: Sorry, I just copied the block out of the initial question. :)

Comment: good point thanks, it's so much easier to judge other people haha

Comment: You don't need the colon.

Answer (score 1):

You can inherit from Struct to make a simple object, and then pass in the attributes to the initializer:

```
class TestObject < Struct.new(:name, :surname, :sex)
end

TestObject.new('Joe', 'Satriani') #=> sex will be nil
```

You can use OpenStruct to make quick value objects with arbitrary attributes:

```
t = OpenStruct(name: 'Joe', surname: 'Satriani')
```

You can include a module like Virtus: https://github.com/solnic/virtus

Or you can do what Chris Heald said.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to use keyword arguments for this. After all, the `Hash` keys are guaranteed to be valid Ruby identifier `Symbol`s since they need to match up with method names. You don't need the capability to pass in arbitrary Ruby objects as keys of the `Hash`.

```
def initialize(**attrs)
  attrs.each do |attr, value| send(:"#{attr}=", value) end
end

TestObject.new(name: 'Joe', surname: 'Satriani')
```

Comment: I am familiar-ed with `*attrs` but what does it means `**attrs` ?

Comment: @Priti: It's the same but for keyword arguments. It collects all superfluous keyword arguments into a `Hash`, just like `*` collects all superfluous positional arguments into an `Array`.